# Rails File Management and Email Distribution combined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file, email

I'm looking to have a file manager on my rails app - similar to dropbox (I was going to follow this tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-a-dropbox-like-file-sharing-site-with-ruby-on-rails--net-17940) but I am also trying to allow users to share the file via emailing it out to a contact list of emails saved in the app.  I currently have a contact list in my `members` controller with `:email` as one of my fields.  I am unsure where how to go about this.  Are there any gems anyone would recommend?

Comment: this question is a little too broad. i think in general you're not going to find a gem for every feature you're going to need. You can find gems for file uploads and emailing, put you're probably going to need to put together the pieces yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `token` field in your file model, which is randomly generated like this `token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64(nil, false)`. Later create an action in files controller accepting the token as param and displaying a file.
You can send url to this action to any emails, which user wants to share file with.

Here is a file manager engine you can use in your Rails app and refer as example of such implementation https://github.com/sergey-koba-mobidev/boxroom-engine (See ShareLinks controller)